# HTML5 video muted attribute not applied using property but applied using setAttribute

Tags: javascript, html, video

I've found a curious inconsistency when working with HTML5 video.

[Compare these two code snippets and take a look at the *Elements* tab in Chrome developer tools](https://async-await.net/pages/html-5-video-muted.html)

```
<body>
  <script>
    const video1 = document.createElement('video');
    video1.autoplay = true;
    video1.muted = true;
    document.body.appendChild(video1);

    const video2 = document.createElement('video');
    video2.setAttribute('autoplay', 'autoplay');
    video2.setAttribute('muted', 'muted');
    document.body.appendChild(video2);
  </script>
</body>
```

For the first `video`, `muted` set using a JS object property wasn't set. For the second one, using `setAttribute` worked and the DOM attribute is set. Interestingly, this is not the case for `autoplay` where it behaves consistently.

Why is that? Is there another example of an attribute behaving this way? Is there a rule to this? How does one tell which attribute's property behaves which way in JS except for testing?

Comment: Works the same for me in Google Chrome Version 68

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The attributes are only used to initialize the properties. They do not reflect the current state.

By setting the properties directly, you update the object, but do not affect the dom attributes.

If you set the `src` of the `video` (*so you can actually see it in action*) you will see that the properties have been properly applied

```js
const video1 = document.createElement('video');

video1.src = 'http://clips.vorwaerts-gmbh.de/big_buck_bunny.mp4';
video1.controls = true;
video1.autoplay = true;
video1.muted = true;

document.body.appendChild(video1);
```

Comment: The code snippet does not work in Google Chrome Version 68, no "muted" attribute in video tag

Comment: Yes, it is odd. Only the `autoplay` attribute updates in the inspector of Chrome and Firefox, but `muted` and `playsInline` do not. However, the attributes are still in effect (i.e. the video is in fact muted).

Comment: @AntonMalyshev `video.defaultMuted` is the property that reflects to the muted attribute

Comment: @luwes thanks so much for the hint to `video.defaultMuted`!