# Video muted attr when screen is less..

Tags: jquery, html, css

I'm using a video on my website. I use sound on dekstop but i want the video to mute on mobile devices. The jquery code doesn't seem to work.

Can anyone help me?

```js
<script>
        $(document).ready(function () {
            $(window).resize(function () {
                if ($(window).width() < 800) {
                    $('video').attr('muted', 'true');
                }
            });
        });
    </script>
```

Comment: yes and it doesn't work

Comment: What part isn't working, the if statement or just setting the `attr`

Answer (score 3):

No need to use resize function, only document.ready is sufficient.

Also changed `$.attr` to `$.prop` and `'true'` to `true`because you need to set the DOM value, [not the XML attribute](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41656297/html5-video-muted-attribute-not-applied-using-property-but-applied-using-setattr)

```
    <script>
        $(document).ready(function () {

                if ($(window).width() < 800) {
                    // no jQuery needed 
                    // document.querySelector('video').muted = true;
                    $('video').prop('muted', true);
                }

        });
    </script>
```

Also you may look at this to check mobile/desktop instead of 800px width,

[Detecting a mobile browser](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11381673/detecting-a-mobile-browser)

Comment: That is, the resize won't occur on a mobile phone unless the user changes orientation

Comment: @Sebbe77 you need to check if 800 is working for you
$(window).width() < 800

Comment: @Sebbe77 "doesn't work" is not a helpful comment. What happened? Did you step through the code? Is it ever reaching that piece of code? Any errors? Did `$('video').attr()` get called?

Comment: @Sebbe77  you need to check if this is working or not $('video').attr('muted', 'true');

Comment: You need to set the DOM property, not the XML attribute, `$('video').prop('muted', true)` You should still follow the advice to not rely on window size, not everybody maximizes their window. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41656297/html5-video-muted-attribute-not-applied-using-property-but-applied-using-setattr @codemirror

Answer (score 0):

instead of detecting screen size, why not try detecting if the device has touch capabilities?

```
var touchDevice = ("ontouchstart" in document.documentElement);
if(touchDevice){
  $('video').prop('muted',true);
}
```

Comment: What if the user is using a touch laptop?

Answer (score 0):

```
if (/Mobi/.test(navigator.userAgent)) {
    $('video').prop('muted',true);
}
```

OR

```
if( /Android|webOS|iPhone|iPad|iPod|BlackBerry|IEMobile|Opera Mini/i.test(navigator.userAgent) ) {
 $('video').prop('muted',true);
}
```

Comment: An answer that doesn't explain what the problem is is not as useful

Answer (score 0):

Simple answer

You need to do 2 things
1: Check if particular device is mobile or desktop/laptop.
2: Mute the video if it is mobile device.

make sure that you know code for both of the 2 things.

**Part 1:**

Let's see if it is a mobile or desktop/laptop
Taken from https://stackoverflow.com/a/11381730/2664160

is a nice solution

```
window.mobilecheck = function() {
  var check = false;
  (function(a){if(/(android|bb\d+|meego).+mobile|avantgo|bada\/|blackberry|blazer|compal|elaine|fennec|hiptop|iemobile|ip(hone|od)|iris|kindle|lge |maemo|midp|mmp|mobile.+firefox|netfront|opera m(ob|in)i|palm( os)?|phone|p(ixi|re)\/|plucker|pocket|psp|series(4|6)0|symbian|treo|up\.(browser|link)|vodafone|wap|windows ce|xda|xiino/i.test(a)||/1207|6310|6590|3gso|4thp|50[1-6]i|770s|802s|a wa|abac|ac(er|oo|s\-)|ai(ko|rn)|al(av|ca|co)|amoi|an(ex|ny|yw)|aptu|ar(ch|go)|as(te|us)|attw|au(di|\-m|r |s )|avan|be(ck|ll|nq)|bi(lb|rd)|bl(ac|az)|br(e|v)w|bumb|bw\-(n|u)|c55\/|capi|ccwa|cdm\-|cell|chtm|cldc|cmd\-|co(mp|nd)|craw|da(it|ll|ng)|dbte|dc\-s|devi|dica|dmob|do(c|p)o|ds(12|\-d)|el(49|ai)|em(l2|ul)|er(ic|k0)|esl8|ez([4-7]0|os|wa|ze)|fetc|fly(\-|_)|g1 u|g560|gene|gf\-5|g\-mo|go(\.w|od)|gr(ad|un)|haie|hcit|hd\-(m|p|t)|hei\-|hi(pt|ta)|hp( i|ip)|hs\-c|ht(c(\-| |_|a|g|p|s|t)|tp)|hu(aw|tc)|i\-(20|go|ma)|i230|iac( |\-|\/)|ibro|idea|ig01|ikom|im1k|inno|ipaq|iris|ja(t|v)a|jbro|jemu|jigs|kddi|keji|kgt( |\/)|klon|kpt |kwc\-|kyo(c|k)|le(no|xi)|lg( g|\/(k|l|u)|50|54|\-[a-w])|libw|lynx|m1\-w|m3ga|m50\/|ma(te|ui|xo)|mc(01|21|ca)|m\-cr|me(rc|ri)|mi(o8|oa|ts)|mmef|mo(01|02|bi|de|do|t(\-| |o|v)|zz)|mt(50|p1|v )|mwbp|mywa|n10[0-2]|n20[2-3]|n30(0|2)|n50(0|2|5)|n7(0(0|1)|10)|ne((c|m)\-|on|tf|wf|wg|wt)|nok(6|i)|nzph|o2im|op(ti|wv)|oran|owg1|p800|pan(a|d|t)|pdxg|pg(13|\-([1-8]|c))|phil|pire|pl(ay|uc)|pn\-2|po(ck|rt|se)|prox|psio|pt\-g|qa\-a|qc(07|12|21|32|60|\-[2-7]|i\-)|qtek|r380|r600|raks|rim9|ro(ve|zo)|s55\/|sa(ge|ma|mm|ms|ny|va)|sc(01|h\-|oo|p\-)|sdk\/|se(c(\-|0|1)|47|mc|nd|ri)|sgh\-|shar|sie(\-|m)|sk\-0|sl(45|id)|sm(al|ar|b3|it|t5)|so(ft|ny)|sp(01|h\-|v\-|v )|sy(01|mb)|t2(18|50)|t6(00|10|18)|ta(gt|lk)|tcl\-|tdg\-|tel(i|m)|tim\-|t\-mo|to(pl|sh)|ts(70|m\-|m3|m5)|tx\-9|up(\.b|g1|si)|utst|v400|v750|veri|vi(rg|te)|vk(40|5[0-3]|\-v)|vm40|voda|vulc|vx(52|53|60|61|70|80|81|83|85|98)|w3c(\-| )|webc|whit|wi(g |nc|nw)|wmlb|wonu|x700|yas\-|your|zeto|zte\-/i.test(a.substr(0,4))) check = true;})(navigator.userAgent||navigator.vendor||window.opera);
  return check;
};
```

`mobilecheck()` will return true if it is a mobile device

**Part 2:**

How to mute video?
You have used
`$('video').attr('muted', 'true');` does it work?

instead of finding solution to two problems at once,
 try to go step by step
first make sure that you have detected if it is mobile or desktop

then try to mute video

if still unsuccessful! come back to this site :)